# Disabling custom form fields with python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I have a custom input form and a script to disable the fields that are currently not needed.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    e_kon_mang = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"e_kon_mang")
    e_kon_mang.setEnabled(False)
```

When I start the editor and then call the input form it works as desired. But if I call the form first and then start the editor, the disabled fields are active again.

As a workaround I even tried to deactivate the fields in the QT Designer, so I have to activate them by script first. But this setting is ignored by QGIS.

Does anyone know what I missed?